# Use PHP to Decode BASE64 encoded Signed Integers in 16bit

Tags: c#, php, arrays

I have a Base64 encoded string and I am using the following c# code to decode it. Inside should be a range of Signed integers stored in 16bit.

Now I need to do it in PHP but I'm having real trouble. Can anyone help?

Basically can anyone convert this code to php?

```
    private string decode(string encoded) 
    {
        Byte[] newBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(
            encoded.Replace("\n","")
        );

        int[] newArr = new int[newBytes.Length / 4];
        for (int ctr = 0; ctr < newBytes.Length / 4; ctr++)
            newArr[ctr] = BitConverter.ToInt16(newBytes, ctr * 4);

        return DisplayArray(newArr);
    }

    private string DisplayArray(Array arr)
    {
        string output = "";
        for (int ctr = 0; ctr < arr.GetUpperBound(0); ctr++)
        {
            output += arr.GetValue(ctr)  + ",";
        }

        return output;      
    }
```

Here is the base64 string....

```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```

and it should decode to...

```
2,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,2,0,0,7,5,5,0,0,0,2,5,5,2,2,0,0,0,2,0,2,5,2,2,2,2,5,2,2,5,5,0,5,2,2,0,5,5,0,2,0,2,2,5,7,5,2,0,2,2,2,2,5,5,2,0,2,2,5,0,-2,2,2,0,2,0,5,5,0,2,2,2,0,0,2,2,2,5,2,5,7,5,5,5,7,7,5,7,7,5,7,7,7,5,2,-2,2,2,5,5,2,2,2,7,2,5,5,0,7,2,5,0,2,2,7,5,2,2,2,7,7,7,7,5,2,5,5,5,10,10,7,10,10,10,12,12,12,17,15,20,20,20,22,17,20,20,22,25,27,27,27,32,35,40,40,40,40,40,37,37,37,40,42,37,35,30,35,25,25,20,15,10,7,2,7,5,2,2,0,0,-2,0,2,-2,0,5,2,0,5,0,0,0,-2,0,-2,0,-2,-2,-5,-2,0,-5,-2,-2, etc...
```

Comment: Try this : Int16[] num = newBytes.Select(x => (Int16)x).ToArray();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The good

PHP makes it really easy to read in base64 data and convert it to an array of signed integers. Make sure to read up on the [unpack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) function, it's great.

```
$stringValue = base64_decode($base64data, true);
$integers = unpack("s*", $stringValue);
```

---

### The bad

*That is not what your C# code is doing*. After converting the base64 into raw bytes, it then processes that data in chunks of 4 bytes, parsing the first 2 into an int16 *and throwing away the second two bytes*. Half your data goes down the drain.

---

### The ugly

If the C# code is really the algorithm you are after, here is how to do it in PHP:

```
$stringValue = base64_decode($base64data, true);
$integers = unpack("s*", $stringValue);
// Throw away half of our data. Because... why not? :)
$integers = array_map('array_shift', array_chunk($integers, 2));
```

Comment: Perfect -- and all in just 2 lines too. I was only looking up unpack earlier but I was clearly missing something.  Sorry, I forgot to change the c# 4 to a 2, in the existing c# project we need to ignore half the data. Thank you very much!